# How to write a sql2 query for find the users have access to particular jcr path in AEM

Tags: aem

i am trying to write a query for find the users who have access to particular JCR path

Also let me know the possibilities in any other.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that's not possible via JCR Query; mostly because the access control system used by Jackrabbit (by default) and AEM relies on inheritance. So the permissions a user has on a certain node is not expressed as a node or properties, but is computed out of inherited ACEs and ACEs directly attached to the node, from both groups (recursivly) and the user itself.

So, you probably need to filter your query result via session.hasPermission(). (Java)